# How do I test a saga that exports an array of effects?

Tags: redux-saga

All of the examples I have seen of saga testing involve testing a function generator, but I'm having a heck of a time trying to test a file that exports an array of redux effects. Here's a bare bones replication of what I'm working with:

```
// file: mysaga.js
export default [
  call(takeEvery, 'startClock', startIt)
]

export function* startIt() {
  while ( true ) {
    yield call(delay, 1000)
  }
}
```

And the test file...

```
// file: mysaga-test.js
import MySagas, { startIt } from './mysaga'

describe('MySaga', () => {
  // Using bdd-lazy-var
  subject(mySagaWrapper())

  it('takes every `startClock`', () => {
    expect($subject.next().value).to.eql(call(takeEvery, 'startClock', startIt))
  })

  it('invokes a delay', () => {
    expect($subject.next().value).to.eql(call(delay, 1000))
  })
})

function* mySagaWrapper() {
  yield* MySagas
}
```

When I run the test, the results I get look like this:

```
MySaga
  ✓ takes every `startClock`
  1) invokes a delay


1 passing (2ms)
1 failing

1) ClockSagas
     invokes a delay:
   AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, CALL) }
    at Context.<anonymous> (...)
```

How do I test what comes after the `takeEvery`?

Also, I'd much prefer not to have to export `*startIt()` since it's not really part of the public API of this file, so I'm eager to find a solution to that problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

The key is basically just to test the function generator (`startIt()`, below) directly:

```
import MySaga, {
 startIt,
} from './mysaga'

describe('MySaga', () => {
  describe('the default export', () => {
    subject(mySagaWrapper())

    it('takes every `startClock`', () => {
      expect($subject.next().value)
        .to.eql(call(takeEvery, 'startClock', startIt))
    })
  })

  // THIS right here
  describe('startIt()', () => {
    subject(startIt())

    it('invokes a delay', () => {
      expect($subject.next().value)
        .to.eql(call(delay, 1000 / 60))
    })
  })
})

function* mySagaWrapper() {
  yield* MySaga
}
```

If your exported array contains multiple effects, like this:

```
// file: mysaga.js
export default [
  call(takeEvery, 'startClock', startIt),
  call(takeEvery, 'foo', doFoo),
]

export function* doFoo() {
}
```

Simply add another test example:

```
  describe('the default export', () => {
    subject(mySagaWrapper())

    it('takes every `startClock`', () => {
      expect($subject.next().value)
        .to.eql(call(takeEvery, 'startClock', startIt))
    })

    it('takes every `foo`', () => {
      expect($subject.next().value)
        .to.eql(call(takeEvery, 'foo', doFoo))
    })
  })
```

This is not what I'd consider an ideal solution since it involves exporting private implementation details, but it definitely makes testing possible.